# sendmail taking lot of time to send email

Tags: debian, sendmail

I have a VPS (Debian) on which I am using sendmail. Problem is sendmail takes a lot of time to actually send email. I searched and found many people are facing same issue and everyone suggested to write following line in hosts file which I have done but still same problem.

> 127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain myhostname

Even if I use following in hosts, problem remains the same.

> 127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain myhostname
>   25.99.12.45 localhost localhost.localdomain myhostname

By the way that `25.99.12.45` is my VPS IP (this is not real IP just dummy one)

**EDIT**

> Aug 10 09:34:43 localhost sendmail[411]: v7BCXh8B100411: from=root,
>   size=15, class=0, nrcpts=1,
>   msgid=<201708101334.v7BCXh8B000411@localhost.localdomain>,
>   relay=root@localhost
>
> Aug 10 09:34:43 localhost sm-mta[412]: v7BCXh8B100412:
>   from=, size=316, class=0, nrcpts=1,
>   msgid=<201708101334.v7BCXh8B100411@localhost.localdomain>,
>   proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
>
> Aug 10 09:35:47 localhost sm-mta[412]: STARTTLS=client,
>   relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL,
>   cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
>
> Aug 10 09:35:47 localhost sm-mta[412]: v7BCXh8B100412:
>   to=, ctladdr= (0/0),
>   delay=00:01:04, xdelay=00:01:04, mailer=esmtp, pri=30316,
>   relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [209.xxx.xxx.xxx], dsn=2.0.0,
>   stat=Sent (OK 1502372147 a130si3247433qkg.282 - gsmtp)
>
> Aug 10 09:35:47 localhost sendmail[411]: v7BCXh8B100411:
>   to=test_email@gmail.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:01:04,
>   xdelay=00:01:04, mailer=relay, pri=30015, relay=[127.0.0.1]
>   [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (v7BCXh8B100412 Message accepted for
>   delivery)

Comment: Do you see anything in  your logs when an email is sent?  Have you looked at a strace or packet capture to see what happening between the message being submitted mta, and the attempt to deliver?

Comment: How long EXACTLY does it take?  EXACT delay in seconds may give some hints.

Comment: Please provide log output (`/var/log/maillog` or `/var/log/mail.log`)

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip takes 1 minute

Comment: @MikeB Mail log given above

Comment: @Zoredache Mail log given above

Comment: Is it **exactly** 60 seconds? [75s typical DNS timeout, 60s = 2 * 30s ident lookup timeout e.g. by tcpwrapers]

Comment: Yes it is almost exactly 60 seconds.

Comment: Try fixing the verify=fail issue, it appears there is where your MTA is spending more of the time.(check the time difference between the log line above and the verify=fail log line)

Answer (score 0):

Simply insert your real FQDN to /etc/mail/sendmail.cf, started with Dj, so like this: "Djmymachine.mydomain.tld" and restart sendmail.